# Insufficient privileges when trying to add Azure Active Directory authentication in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, active-directory

I'm starting a new project that will use ASP.NET Core Web App to login users using an AD domain.

When I try to add 'Work or School Accounts' with Azure AD authentication in VS I am greeted by this window. Could someone point me in the right direction where I need to look to solve this issue? Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image: Error]

Comment: How did you tried include the steps, there are couple of reason for this message. Its tough to guess anything with this picture.

Comment: I added a few more pics, hopefully it helps!

Comment: I am coder don't deal with picture, show me code or steps you tried or communicate with a graphics designer as they might have good sense of picture.

Comment: Please confirm : you input the correct domain and you have enough permission to create applications in Azure AD .